# How to use a spinner with custom layouts using a cursor adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-cursoradapter

My objective is to convert a working spinner (populated via a cursor adapter) to have alternating backgrounds. Similar to :-

[image]

Currently I have this, where everything works fine :-

[image]

This is the relevant working code within the cursor adpater (i.e. with the plain dropdowns) :-

```
@Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_aisle_shop_list_selector, parent, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        determineViewBeingProcessed(view,"BindV",-1);

        TextView shopname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.aaslstv01);
        shopname.setText(cursor.getString(shops_shopname_offset));

    }
```

I have tried adding an override of the **`getDropDownView`** (code as below). I get the alternating row colors as I want but the dropdown views are blank. However, if I click outside of the selector, then they get populated with data (hence how I managed to get the screen shot, shown above, of what I want). Selection sets the correct Item.

If I remove the **`return`** after inflating the layout, then the dropdown views are populated but with data from other rows (however,selection selects the correct item)

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertview;
        determineViewBeingProcessed(v,"GetDDV",position);
        if( v == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_aisle_shop_list_entry, parent, false);
            return v;
        }
        Context context = v.getContext();

        TextView shopname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aasletv01);

        shopname.setText(getCursor().getString(shops_shopname_offset));

        if(position % 2 == 0) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorlistviewroweven));
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorlistviewrowodd));
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clues were they I just didn't think hard enough. The issue is with the cursor being in the wrong position because the cursor needs to be obtained via `getCursor()`.

Additionally, the **`return`** after the inflate, is premature (this has been commented out).

Adding **`getCursor().moveToPosition(position);`** before accessing data from the cursor resolves the problem.

Alternately (*perhaps more correctly, comments appreciated on whether or not one method is more correct than the other*). Adding:-

```
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
```

and then replacing subsequent `getCursor()` with `cursor` (*not mandatory*) also works.

So the final code for **getDropDownView** method could be:-

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertview;
        determineViewBeingProcessed(v,"GetDDV",position);
        if( v == null) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_aisle_shop_list_entry, parent, false);
            //return v;
        }
        Context context = v.getContext();
        Cursor cursor = getCursor();
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);


        TextView shopname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.aasletv01);

        shopname.setText(cursor.getString(shops_shopname_offset));

        if(position % 2 == 0) {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorlistviewroweven));
        } else {
            v.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.colorlistviewrowodd));
        }
        return v;
    }
```